# Existe alguma diferença entre salvar as configurações em dotEnv, JSON ou INI?

Tags: php, json, ini

Para salvar dados sensíveis da aplicação, é recomendado salvar em dotEnv ou eu posso salvar em qualquer outro formato sendo que o arquivo não está no diretório public?

Vejo muitos falando sobre o dotEnv, queria saber o porquê de dizerem que o mesmo é tão seguro, sendo que é praticamente idêntico ao .ini. Quais são as diferenças?

Comment: Creio que seguro só se for criptografado.

Comment: Costumo criar um config.php e jogar as variáveis de configuração nele. Se alguém acha isso uma prática ruim, gostaria de saber o porquê.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amigo, dotEnv é mais uma padronização de facilidade. Antes era XML agora é Json, mais ou menos isso. Um .ini ou config.php em questão de segurança é a mesma coisa, você pode dar require acima de public_html e ninguém na web verá o arquivo. A questão do dotEnv é sua facilidade, carrega ele de algum lugar escondido e depois é só usar $_ENV['senha_bd'] quando precisar, nada de código mirabolante ou gambiarra.